# how to make gdb set breakpoint on some condition?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb

I've found out where caused SEGSEV, but only happens when that function be called hundreds of thousands times to trigger some rare case, is it possible to set breakpoint there when something is true? either on the gdb command line or c source file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
(gdb) break file.c:15 if some_variable == some_value
```

Answer (score 0):

(gdb) cond n variable==value

where n is the number of the gdb breakpoint